# How do I search for Twitter polls I voted?

Tags: twitter, twitter-search

Apart from liking or bookmarking tweets with polls, how can I later find polls where I voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no poll history on twitter.

IIRC, twitter used to send a push notification when a poll you have voted in was finished so that you could check the results. I think they have stopped that as well (I haven't got any poll notifications recently even though I have voted in plenty of polls). Now, you only get a notification when your own poll is finished.